# React Native - React Navigation Drawer How to make a drawer inside drawer ? (Double Menu)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I'm looking a way to make a drawer inside a drawer like a double menu. Here is what I want to make it.

[image: https://dribbble.com/shots/2139038-Double-menu]
https://dribbble.com/shots/2139038-Double-menu

```js
const drawerNavigatorConfig = {
  drawerType: "slide"
};


export const Navigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: "Home Screen"
      }
    },
    test: {
      screen: TestScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        drawerLabel: "Test Screen"
      }
    },
  },
  drawerNavigatorConfig
);
```

I simply could not find a way to achieve this double menu idea.

Comment: Are u solve it? :v

Comment: Unfortunately no :( Still looking for a solution for it.. I mean at least not a completely custom solution

Comment: Interesting, Designers Will kill us :D, I think if u used Animation API maybe will have an opportunity to achieve it but u think No :D if you do anything share it

Comment: Of course I will share anything if I find something else. It is possible with complete custom animation API however it is possible with drawer navigation I think :(

Comment: I will play with it when I have time so when u do a project push it to GitHub and let me know

Comment: Sure will do, please inform me if you get a good solution also we can work on it together :)

Comment: Hello @FreakyCoder , I do it with friend check it here and let me know ur opinion , https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/double-menu-with-catalin

Comment: UH S** it's not saved before, check these https://snack.expo.io/@anastely/double-menu

Comment: I'm gonna check it out today :)

Comment: @DevAS woaa :O It actually works, I'm also gonna work on it at the weekend.

Comment: Are you check it?

Comment: Yep, It looks awesome but I could not spend time to work on it. I'm going to work on it this weekend :) But I hate Expo tho :D

Comment: Haha me too :D, I just write it on expo to save more time when installing all dependency, I know it's irrelevant but can you work with mapbox before? Or check my question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266242/consideration-directions-between-two-point-location-in-mapbox-gl-react-native

Comment: I did, I'm gonna check it

Comment: @DevAS can you please re share your twitter? We need to talk about this project and mapbox one

Comment: Here's https://mobile.twitter.com/AnasNTy